# Best practices for debugging the Rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, sass

I'm working with a Rails 3 app, `bootstrap-sass`, and the asset pipeline, and I'm looking for some ideas on how to debug asset pipelines woes.

When working in development, and compiling on the fly (i.e. including from lots of compiled css files), my app looks exactly how I expect it to.

However when I use the asset pipeline to to compile assets into a single file, to test how it will behave in production, I think validation errors in the concatenated file `application.css` are causing browsers to stop evaluating the css correctly, and I'm seeing a number of display issues.

When I look at the generated css files in development, and pass them through a css3 validator, I can see that validation errors occur when working with the vendored css files (in most cases these are due to vendor specific hacks, setting off the validator) - the files I've generated are passing validation when I run them through the w3c validator, and I've listed the pass/fail results in the sprockets files below:

```
/*
 * sprocket file in application.css
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require vendor
 *= require bootstrap-include # FAILS 474 ERRORS - presumably down to css hacks
 *= require DT_bootstrap      # FAILS TWO ERRORS - presumably down to css hacks again
 *= require navbar            # PASSES
 *= require footer            # PASSES
 *= require main              # PASSES
 *= require home              # PASSES
 *= require widget            # PASSES
 *= require search            # PASSES
 *= require devise            # PASSES
 *= require doohickeys        # PASSES
 *= require datepicker        # FAILS - again yet more cross browser css hacks suspected
*/
```

#### How should you start prepping files for production when concatenation breaks an app's visuals like this?

I'm asking on here to get an idea of how best to debug a compiled stylesheet like this - it sounds like something that has been solved before elegantly, but I'm not aware of a reliable, approach when dealing with a problem like this.

For example, I can see that some rules are not being evaluated by using web developer inspector tools in Firefox and Webkit, but it's not clear to me how to go beyond that, short of doing some laborious binary search on the compiled CSS.

Surely there are some more specialised tools available for situations like this already, like being able to compile only some files in `application.css`, and link to a precompiled `bootstrap-sass` file separately, or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

You should not use Sprocket directives if you are using something like bootstrap-sass, you should use `@import`.

Rename your manifest file from `application.css` to `application.css.scss`, then `@import` away, example:

```
@import "frameworks";
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

Comment: Thanks Kain - why would this be an issue, and why would it only affect production?

Comment: would be interested in a better understanding of this too... thanks for any feedback!