# Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "[": expected "|", was "]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm getting that error when try to run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`. This is my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'httparty'
# Babel
gem 'sprockets-commoner'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more:          https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"

gem 'bower-rails'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"

gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development do
  gem "capistrano", "~> 3.8"
  gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
end

group :development, :test do
 # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger    console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in  the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

And this is the error output:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides  /extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
(called from block in <class:Railtie> at /home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/less-rails-2.8.0/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:16)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are using the a deprecated processor interface    Less::Rails::ImportProcessor.
Please update your processor interface:
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
(called from block in <class:Railtie> at /home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/less-rails-2.8.0/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:21)
** Invoke bower:before_precompile (first_time)
** Execute bower:before_precompile
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "[": expected "|", was "]"
(sass):41
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass  /scss/parser.rb:1207:in `expected'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1137:in `expected'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1132:in `tok!'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/static_parser.rb:262:in `attrib_name!'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/static_parser.rb:229:in `attrib'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/static_parser.rb:152:in `simple_selector_sequence'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/static_parser.rb:111:in `selector'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/static_parser.rb:86:in `selector_comma_sequence'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1115:in `expr!'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/static_parser.rb:20:in `parse_selector'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:427:in `visit_rule'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/efrain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/efrain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@xxxx/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

I'm using ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 5.0.1

I have searched similar post but they doesn't help me to resolve the problem.
I would appreciate a lot any help.

Comment: Can you follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658751/rails-finding-out-which-file-causes-sasssyntaxerror-exception) and then update with the contents of the file causing the error if you need further help tracking it down?

Comment: Hi @SimpleLime thanks for your comment. I tried the link you sent me but I always get blank lines when I use `puts filename` also I used `puts "Test: #{filename.inspect}"` and I got `nil`.

Comment: Hmm, might have to go old school on this and just remove files one by one until the command runs and then you know the last file you removed has the issue. Until you know which CSS file has the invalid syntax there isn't much you can do, let alone people who have no idea what any of your code looks like.

Comment: @SimpleLime I found the error! The project use an html theme called `Polo` and this use Bootstrap so in the `bootstrap.min.css` there was the problematic syntax, something like this: `[] { cursor: pointer; }`. To get that file I started to comment lines in the `application.css` file to know what require was causing the problem. Thanks for your interest in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This a very specific case but maybe it can help someone.

The project use an html theme called Polo and this use Bootstrap so in the `bootstrap.min.css` there was the problematic syntax, something like this: `[] { cursor: pointer; }` so I get rid of it. To get that file I started to comment lines in the `application.css` file to know what require was causing the problem.